# Samba service fail / not working

Tags: samba

Suddenly my samba service doesn't work.

root@prodappsexternalteam:~# systemctl start smbd
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xeu smbd.service" for details.
root@prodappsexternalteam:~# systemctl status smbd
× smbd.service - LSB: Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; generated)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-11-15 22:27:30 UTC; 1min 37s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 2888 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 286ms

Nov 15 22:27:30 prodappsexternalteam systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Nov 15 22:27:30 prodappsexternalteam smbd[2888]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Nov 15 22:27:30 prodappsexternalteam smbd[2888]:    ...fail!
Nov 15 22:27:30 prodappsexternalteam systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 15 22:27:30 prodappsexternalteam systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 15 22:27:30 prodappsexternalteam systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).

root@prodappsexternalteam:~# testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

WARNING: The 'netbios name' is too long (max. 15 chars).

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

## Global parameters

[global]
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
logging = file
map to guest = Bad User
max log size = 1000
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
server role = standalone server
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
unix password sync = Yes
usershare allow guests = Yes
idmap config * : backend = tdb

[html]
guest ok = Yes
path = /var/www/html
read only = No
valid users = devs

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. Instead, copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: You have a typo in `guest` (written as `guesk`). Correct that, and try again.